# Should a summer-switch to toggle between baseboard heater and heat exchanger between the baseboard heater and thermostat or before the thermostat

Tags: hvac

This morning I had a heat-exchanger installed in my house.

My breaker-panel didn't have any open spaces on it, so the heat-exchanger was installed using a summer-switch.  In the winter my house is heated with baseboard heaters.  The summer switch toggles between the baseboard heaters and new heat-exchanger unit.

I was surprised to learn that the summer-switch was installed after the baseboard heater thermostat.  Like this:

```
 Breaker
     │
     │
     ▼
 Baseboard Thermostat
     │
     │
     ▼
 Summer Switch───────────────►Heat Exchanger
     │
     │
     ▼
 Baseboard Heater
```

I feel like it would have made more sense to wire it like this:

```
 Breaker
     │
     │
     ▼
 Summer Switch───────────────►Heat Exchanger
     │
     │
     ▼
 Baseboard Thermostat
     │
     │
     ▼
 Baseboard Heater
```

The way that it is wired creates a minor issue:

The thermostat reaches a maximum temperature of 25C or 30C (77F or 86F).  If the house is warmer than that, you cannot turn on the AC because the thermostat will cut-off the electricity.

The installer suggested that if this happens that I could place a ice-pack on my thermostat to trick it into thinking that it was cooler than it is.

**Question:** Is it normal to have the summer switch for a heat exchanger after the thermostat?

Comment: That is the biggest bone head comment I have ever heard (ice pack) . It may have saved a bunch to do it this way and a simple override on the thermostat would eliminate the problem. Although we don’t know how it was bid cheapest way or ? I kind of agree with @gil

Answer (score 2):

Your logic is correct. I would suggest not using that installer again and reporting his comments to his manager and if you purchased new equipment he installed report it to the equipment manufacturer as well. Then ask for somebody to inspect and validate his work as it is not working. You may have financial recourse as well but that is up to you and where you live.